# converting a ps image to gif image with length x900 y800

Tags: image, gif, ghostscript, postscript

I have a ps image that I want to convert to a gif image with horizontal by vertical dimensions of 900 and 800 respectively.  I have tried to use the command:

```
convert panel.gs -resize x800 y900 panel.gif
```

or also:

```
convert panel.gs -resize 900x800 panel.gif
```

Can you help me to tweak the convert commands so I can get the desired results?

Comment: You maybe want to use an (escaped) exclamation mark after the resize to allow distortion and get exact output size `convert input.eps -resize 900x800\! result.gif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.gs is not a valid suffix. Did you mean .ps?

Imagemagick will need ghostscript as a delegate. You did not say what was wrong nor what platform or what version of Imagemagick.

If the image does not have the same aspect ratio as the final dimensions you want, you will either 1) need to distort it to fit using !, 2) resize it and then extend to the size you want filling with background color, or 3) resize it with ^ and crop it to the size you want.

```
convert panel.ps -resize "900x800!" panel.gif

convert panel.ps -resize 900x800 -gravity center -background white -extent 900x800 panel.gif

convert panel.ps -resize "900x800^" -gravity center -extent 900x800 panel.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly you haven't actually said what's wrong with the two commands that you have tried already.....

Your PostScript program probably does not contain an 'image' as such, PostScript is not a bitmap format its a programming language.

You can use Ghostscript to render the PostScript to an image, and then use ImageMagick to resize that image, possibly you can combine these two steps, or just perform a single conversion, it depends on what exactly you want to happen, which isn't clear.

If (for example) your PostScript program requests a media size of 9 inches by 8 then you can create a bitmap image by simply setting the resolution to 100 dpi using `-r100`.

If you want the image scaled differently in each direction, then you need to set a non-square resolution. For example if the PostScript program requests media of 9 inches by 4 then you need to set the resolution to 100x200 in order to get an image exactly 900 x 800 pixels. You would use `-r100x200` for this.

The alternative, from a PostScript point of view, is to set the media size to a given 
value in pixels (using `-g900x800`) and set `-dDFIXEDMEDIA` which prevents the PostScript program from changing it. You can then use `-dFitPage` which will have Ghostscript scale the content to fit the page. However it will scale the content equally in both directions, which may leave white space around the edge.

Now since Ghostscritp doesn't write GIF directly you'll need to load whatever bitmap format you select into IM in order to write it out as a GIF, so perhaps the simplest solution is just to use Ghostscript to render the PostScript to a defined resolution (eg 100 dpi) and then load that image into IM and rescale it there.

Since IM (and therefore convert) use Ghostscript to process PostScript programs, that's what's happening now so it isn't obvious to me what your problem is.